# How to extract key from maptype to use it in agg function (spark dataframe)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i'm reading some data from a `parquet file` with spark using scala and dataframes and i'm trying to extract from a maptype key and using it into a `groupby` function.

HERE's an exemple :

```
    val sh = StructType(Array(
   StructField("sessionId", StringType, true),
 StructField("productTypes", MapType(StringType, IntegerType, true))) 

df.select(
col("productTypes"),
   col("sessionId")
)
    .withcolumn("output".select(explode(col("productTypes"))).select("key")
```

)
but that throws an exception

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
[error]     (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
[error] .withColumn("col4", df.select(explode((col("productTypes")))).select("key"))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be much easier to answer your question if you add a clear example of the input and the expected output. You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55855078/edit) button to edit your question and add the necessary information.

Comment: Hi @Khaoula your syntax has errors. select and withcolumn are members of a Dataframe. You can use withColumn after a select but not a select within withColumn

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis i know.... but i wish if i had something that will do something similar ....i cant use a select inside a select statement that's one .. two, when i select other attributes with the function explode and then use .select("key") only the key value is being selected